# Execute Dynamic SQL with Concated Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have multiple columns with names like "abc", "abc1", "abc2", "abc3".
My goal is to push the value to the next column, so:

```
abc3 = abc2
abc2 = abc1
abc1 = abc
abc = null
```

I wrote this:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(20)
SET @name = 'abc'

DECLARE @exec nvarchar(max)
SET @exec = 
    'UPDATE ' + @tbl + '
        SET ' + @name + '3 = ' + @name + '2,
        ' + @name + '2 = ' + @name + '1,
        ' + @name + '1 = ' + @name + ',
        ' + @name + '= ''''

EXEC sp_executesql @exec
```

But if I want to change the name "abc" in something else and execute the query once again, the name does not update.

I found a way to assign the value within the sp_executesql command, however I'm not able to concat the namevalue with the numbers that way.

Is it possible to create a query like that, where I can execute it multiple times with different names?

My idea is to run it like that and change the names there.

```
EXEC sp_executesql @exec, N'@name nvarchar(20)', @name = N'abc'
EXEC sp_executesql @exec, N'@name nvarchar(20)', @name = N'xyz'
```

Comment: You have a problem with your data model.  This operation should not be desired in any application.

Comment: why can you not concat the name and number?  Do you get an error?  If so what is it?  I can run your query and print out the @exec value and it looks fine to me (but can not test without your table structures or anything.

Comment: object names cannot be parameterized - including table and column.

Comment: *Never* inject unsanitised strings into a dynamic statement. `QUOTENAME` exists for a reason; properly quote your objects and **parametrise** your calls to `sys.sp_executesql` don't inject the values (in this case, the value of `@name` on the otherside of the `=`.

Answer (score 2):

This, honestly, is a really odd requirement. It looks like the real problem is your design as it's denormalised (there should only be 1 `name` column, not 4).

Anyway, you *can* achieve this with dynamic SQL yes. Note you need to ensure you properly quote your dynamic objects, *and* parametrise values that aren't dynamic (such as your missing `WHERE`). This handles the safe injection, but it's ugly as anything...

```sql
DECLARE @schema sysname, --The data type used for object names. Synonym for nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
        @table sysname,
        @name sysname; 
--Assign @schema and @table too
SET @Name = N'abc';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@table) + @CRLF +
           N'SET ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + N' = '''',' + @CRLF +
           N'    ' + QUOTENAME(@name + '1') + N' = ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + N',' + @CRLF +
           N'    ' + QUOTENAME(@name + '2') + N' = ' + QUOTENAME(@name + '1') + N',' + @CRLF +
           N'    ' + QUOTENAME(@name + '3') + N' = ' + QUOTENAME(@name + '2') + N';';
           --No WHERE?

--PRINT @SQL --Your Best Friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I feel like this is just a (much) better way of writing my already existing query. I am trying to now do exactly that, but with a way of changing the variable "@name" to run it multiple times without copying the whole thing over and over again. I do know it's a weird use-case, but I kinda need it that way as of now.

Is there a way to run this with a set list of different names or something like "EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @name" after setting a different name again?

(btw, I do have a WHERE statement, just deleted it while abstracting my question)

Comment: It sounds like you're moving the goal posts here, @brainlordy . If you have a new question, you should post a new one.